# CALayer's already present on the screen before animating them

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

So I have a bar chart where each bar is a **CALayer**. I want to animate each layer with a different delay.

```
private func drawBar(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
    // create animation
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + StaticVars.delay
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos
    animation.duration = 2.0
    StaticVars.delay += 0.1

    // create bar
    let barLayer = CALayer()
    barLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    barLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)
    barLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    barLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
}
```

This works well, but there is one issue: the chart is already present on the screen, than it waits for the delay (0.1) than it starts animating each layer with a delay.

I can't understand why the chart is already showing. What I want is when the app appears on the screen the bars should not be visible, just after the first delay should the chart start animating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the layer to appear to have the `fromValue` for the time before it begins (as set using the `beginTime`) you can configure it to fill "backwards" by setting the `fillMode` to [`.backwards`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfillmode/1427660-backwards):

```
animation.fillMode = .backwards
```

Without this, the animation will display the model value (the height of the actual frame of the layer) for all times before the beginTime and after beginTime + duration:

[image]

With this change, the animation will fill any value before the begin time with the `fromValue` (by clamping any time before the begin time to the start of the animation):

[image]

Comment: This was easy and simple :)

Comment: Hey, i've read most of your answers and your website posts about animations and it feels like you're the most knowledgeable around in regards to the topic. I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour during the animation when i also set the model layer values. Could you please take a look here, and maybe give me some hints about it? Thanks, Alberto. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749372/unexpected-behaviour-in-animation-when-i-change-the-properties-of-the-model-laye