# Unexpected behaviour in animation when i change the properties of the model layers

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456642/origami-transition-using-catransform3d-perspective) post, i'm trying to adapt the animations to landscape mode. Basically what i want is to rotate all layers of -90° (90° clockwise) and the animations to run horizontally instead of vertically. The author didn't bother to explain the logic under the hood, there are a dozen paper folding libraries in obj-c which are all based on the same architecture, so apparently this is the way to go for folding.

**EDIT**: To further clarify what i want to achieve, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BURmA.jpg) you can look at three snapshots (starting point, halftime and ending point) of the animations i want. In the question from the link up above the animation collapses from bottom to top, while i want it to collapse from left to right.

Down below you can take a look at the the original project a bit tweaked:

- i changed the gray `bottomSleeve` layer final angle value, as well as the red and blue ones angle;
- i paused the animations on initialization by setting the `perspectiveLayer` `speed` equal to `0` and added a slider, the slider value is then set equal to the `perspectiveLayer` `timeOffset` so that you can interactively run each frame of the animations by sliding. When the touch event on the slider ends, the animations are then resumed from the frame relative to the current `timeOffset` to the final value.
- i changed all the model layers values before running each animation added to the relative presentation layer using `CATransaction`. Also, on completion the `perspectiveLayer` speed is set to `0` again.
- for a better visual understanding, i set the `perspectiveLayer` `backgroundColor` equal to `cyan`.

Just to point it out, there are two main functions:

1. `setupLayers()`, called in `viewDidLoad()` is responsible of setting up the layers positions and anchor points, as well as adding them as sublayers to the `mainView` layer.
2. `animate()`, called recursively in `setupLayers()`, responsible of adding the animations. Here i also set the model layers values to the related animations final value before adding them.

Just copy, paste it and run:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var transform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
var topSleeve: CALayer = CALayer()
var middleSleeve: CALayer = CALayer()
var bottomSleeve: CALayer = CALayer()
var topShadow: CALayer = CALayer()
var middleShadow: CALayer = CALayer()
let width: CGFloat = 300
let height: CGFloat = 150
var firstJointLayer: CATransformLayer = CATransformLayer()
var secondJointLayer:CATransformLayer = CATransformLayer()
var sizeHeight: CGFloat = 0
var positionY: CGFloat = 0

var perspectiveLayer: CALayer = {
    let perspectiveLayer = CALayer()
    perspectiveLayer.speed = 0.0
    perspectiveLayer.fillMode = .removed
    return perspectiveLayer
}()

var mainView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()

private let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(slide(sender:event:)) , for: .valueChanged)
    return slider
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(slider)
    setupLayers()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    slider.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width/3,
                          y: view.bounds.size.height/10*8,
                          width: view.bounds.size.width/3,
                          height: view.bounds.size.height/10)
}

@objc private func slide(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
        
        switch touchEvent.phase {
        case .ended:
            resumeLayer(layer: perspectiveLayer)
        default:
            perspectiveLayer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(sender.value)
        }
        
    }
}

private func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}

private func setupLayers() {
    
    mainView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: width, height: height*3))
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view.addSubview(mainView)
    
    perspectiveLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height*2)
    perspectiveLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    mainView.layer.addSublayer(perspectiveLayer)
    
    firstJointLayer.fillMode = .removed
    firstJointLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    perspectiveLayer.addSublayer(firstJointLayer)
    
    topSleeve.fillMode = .removed
    topSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    topSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    topSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    topSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    firstJointLayer.addSublayer(topSleeve)
    topSleeve.masksToBounds = true
    
    secondJointLayer.fillMode = .removed
    secondJointLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    secondJointLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height*2)
    secondJointLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    secondJointLayer.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height)
    firstJointLayer.addSublayer(secondJointLayer)
    
    secondJointLayer.fillMode = .removed
    middleSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    middleSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    middleSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    middleSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    secondJointLayer.addSublayer(middleSleeve)
    middleSleeve.masksToBounds = true
    
    bottomSleeve.fillMode = .removed
    bottomSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: width, height: height)
    bottomSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    bottomSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    bottomSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height)
    secondJointLayer.addSublayer(bottomSleeve)
    
    firstJointLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    firstJointLayer.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    
    topShadow.fillMode = .removed
    topSleeve.addSublayer(topShadow)
    topShadow.frame = topSleeve.bounds
    topShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    topShadow.opacity = 0
    
    middleShadow.fillMode = .removed
    middleSleeve.addSublayer(middleShadow)
    middleShadow.frame = middleSleeve.bounds
    middleShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    middleShadow.opacity = 0
    
    transform.m34 = -1/700
    perspectiveLayer.sublayerTransform = transform
    
    sizeHeight = perspectiveLayer.bounds.size.height
    positionY = perspectiveLayer.position.y
    
    animate()
}


private func animate() {
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        if self == nil { return }
        self?.perspectiveLayer.speed = 0
    }
    
    firstJointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-85*Double.pi/180), 1, 0, 0)
    secondJointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(170*Double.pi/180), 1, 0, 0)
    bottomSleeve.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-165*Double.pi/180), 1, 0, 0)
    perspectiveLayer.bounds.size.height = 0
    perspectiveLayer.position.y = 0
    topShadow.opacity = 0.5
    middleShadow.opacity = 0.5
    
    var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -85*Double.pi/180
    firstJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 170*Double.pi/180
    secondJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -165*Double.pi/180
    bottomSleeve.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = sizeHeight
    animation.toValue = 0
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = positionY
    animation.toValue = 0
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    topShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    middleShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()

}
}
```

As you can see the animations run as expected, at this point in order to rotate the whole thing it should be just a matter of changing positions, anchor points and final animations values.
Taken from an answer from the link above, here is a great representation of all the layers of the starting project:

[image]

Then i proceeded to refactor `setupLayers()` and `animate()` to run the animations horizontally, from left to right (in other words, i'm rotating of 90° clockwise the up above layers representation).

Once the code is changed to rotate the animations, i encounter two issues:

1. when the animations start, the `firstJointLayer` position translate from left to right along the `perspectiveLayer`. To be fair to my understanding this should be an expected behaviour, as it is a sublayer of `perspectiveLayer`, actually i'm not sure why in the original project it doesn't happen. However, to fix this, i've added another animation responsible of translating it from right to left in its relative system, so that it actually appears stationary. At this point while i don't change the model layers final values (commented lines in the down below project), the animations run horizontally as expected. If i didn't have to also modify the model layers, my goal would be reached as this is the exact animation i want. However...
2. ...if i then try to set the animations final values (just comment the lines out) i get an unexpected behaviour. At the initial frame of the animations, the red, blue and gray layers appear folded on each other, thus the rotations don't work as predicted anymore. Here are some snapshots at time 0.0, 0.5 and 1.0 (duration: 1.0): [image] [image] [image]

The most illogical part to me is that setting the model layers values equal to the presentation layers final values causes the bug, but it only affects the presentation layers, as once the animations are over the model layers below are in the expected (and wanted) rotation/position:
[image]

The anchor points are for sure placed right as the rotations happen around the correct points. I think it may be related to issue 1., but i've tried to reposition the layers multiple times with no success. To the present day this is still unsolved, in two days i wasn't able to track down the primary issue and thus to fix it. To me the original project (up above) and the rotated project (down below) look the same in the logic under the hood.

**EDIT2:** i've found out a minor bug in the code, i was animating the firstJointLayer x position from a starting value equal to the perspectiveLayer x position instead of his own x position, i've fixed it but nothing changed.

**EDIT3**: Since setting the model layers values equal to the animation final values is what causes the bug, please note that using `animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards` and `animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false` is not a viable workaround for avoiding to touch the modal layers, as i need to revert the animation at a later time thus keeping presentation and model layers synced is required.

Any help is really appreciated. Down here the rotated project -  i've also commented the blocks i've changed from the up above project:

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
var transform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
var topSleeve: CALayer = CALayer()
var middleSleeve: CALayer = CALayer()
var bottomSleeve: CALayer = CALayer()
var topShadow: CALayer = CALayer()
var middleShadow: CALayer = CALayer()
let width: CGFloat = 200
let height: CGFloat = 300
var firstJointLayer: CALayer = CATransformLayer()
var secondJointLayer: CALayer = CATransformLayer()
var sizeWidth: CGFloat = 0
var positionX: CGFloat = 0
var firstJointLayerPositionX: CGFloat = 0


var perspectiveLayer: CALayer = {
    let perspectiveLayer = CALayer()
    perspectiveLayer.speed = 0.0
    perspectiveLayer.fillMode = .removed
    return perspectiveLayer
}()

var mainView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()

private let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(slide(sender:event:)) , for: .valueChanged)
    return slider
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(slider)
    setupLayers()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    slider.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width/3,
                          y: view.bounds.size.height/10*8,
                          width: view.bounds.size.width/3,
                          height: view.bounds.size.height/10)

}

@objc private func slide(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
        
        switch touchEvent.phase {
        case .ended:
            resumeLayer(layer: perspectiveLayer)
        default:
                perspectiveLayer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(sender.value)

        }
        
    }
}

private func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}

private func setupLayers() {
    
   // Changing all anchor points and positions here, in order to rotate the whole thing of -90°

    mainView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: width*3, height: height))
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view.addSubview(mainView)
    
    perspectiveLayer.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0, width: width*2, height: height)
    perspectiveLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    mainView.layer.addSublayer(perspectiveLayer)
    
    firstJointLayer.fillMode = .removed
    firstJointLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    firstJointLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    firstJointLayer.position = CGPoint(x: width*2, y: height/2)
    perspectiveLayer.addSublayer(firstJointLayer)
    
    topSleeve.fillMode = .removed
    topSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    topSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    topSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    topSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width*3, y: height/2)
    firstJointLayer.addSublayer(topSleeve)
    topSleeve.masksToBounds = true
    
    secondJointLayer.fillMode = .removed
    secondJointLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    secondJointLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width*2, height: height)
    secondJointLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    secondJointLayer.position = CGPoint(x: width*2, y: height/2)
    firstJointLayer.addSublayer(secondJointLayer)
    
    secondJointLayer.fillMode = .removed
    middleSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    middleSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    middleSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    middleSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width*2, y: height/2)
    secondJointLayer.addSublayer(middleSleeve)
    middleSleeve.masksToBounds = true
    
    bottomSleeve.fillMode = .removed
    bottomSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    bottomSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    bottomSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    bottomSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width, y: height/2)
    secondJointLayer.addSublayer(bottomSleeve)
    
    topShadow.fillMode = .removed
    topSleeve.addSublayer(topShadow)
    topShadow.frame = topSleeve.bounds
    topShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    topShadow.opacity = 0
    
    middleShadow.fillMode = .removed
    middleSleeve.addSublayer(middleShadow)
    middleShadow.frame = middleSleeve.bounds
    middleShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    middleShadow.opacity = 0
    
    transform.m34 = -1/700
    perspectiveLayer.sublayerTransform = transform
    
    sizeWidth = perspectiveLayer.bounds.size.width
    positionX = perspectiveLayer.position.x
    firstJointLayerPositionX = firstJointLayer.position.x

    
    animate()
}


private func animate() {
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        if self == nil { return }
        self?.perspectiveLayer.speed = 0
    }
    
  //        firstJointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-85*Double.pi/180), 0, 1, 0)
  //        secondJointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(170*Double.pi/180), 0, 1, 0)
  //        bottomSleeve.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-165*Double.pi/180), 0, 1, 0)
  //        perspectiveLayer.bounds.size.width = 0
  //        perspectiveLayer.position.x = 600
  //        firstJointLayer.position.x = 0
  //        topShadow.opacity = 0.5
  //        middleShadow.opacity = 0.5
    
    var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -85*Double.pi/180
    firstJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 170*Double.pi/180
    secondJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -165*Double.pi/180
    bottomSleeve.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = sizeWidth
    animation.toValue = 0
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = positionX
    animation.toValue = 600
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

  // As said above, i added this animation which is not included in the original project, as the firstJointLayer was translating his position from left to right along with the perspectiveLayer position, so i make a reverse translation in its relative system so that it is stationary in the mainView system

    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = firstJointLayerPositionX 
    animation.toValue = 0
    firstJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    topShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    middleShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    CATransaction.commit()

}

}
```

Comment: Not quite clear... leaving your commented lines commented, are you getting the start and animation you want, as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/0xRXrWP ? But, your goal is to have it "collapse into the center" as opposed to collapsing left-to-right?

Comment: @DonMag i apologize for not being clear, i've edited the post at the top to show some snapshots of the animation i want. Basically i want the exact same animation you see with the commented lines, collapsed from left to right (opposed to the original project of the linked question from which i took the logic, whose animation collapse from bottom to top). The problem here is that once you comment out the lines, the presentation layers go wild and i don't know why.

Comment: @DonMag also, i've found out a minor bug related to firstJointLayer animation and i've edited the code fixing it,  i let you know this in case you were testing using the code i've posted. I've also commented in the code of the bottom project the lines i've changed from the first project to the bottom project to better clarify the actual changes

Comment: hmm... the images you link to in your edit *"of the animations I want"* appear to be exactly what I see when I run your code, as shown in the images I linked to?

Comment: @DonMag actually they are, until you leave the commented lines, commented. But if you   uncomment the lines, then the animations are different, while they shouldn't be (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3neXN.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpfyA.png ). Maybe i'm not explaining myself in the right way, let me know if i need to further edit the post

Comment: What are the commented lines supposed to accomplish? Is the problem that after the animation finishes, it snaps back to "flat" and you want it to remain "folded"?

Comment: @DonMag the commented lines set the model layers value equal to the final animation values (so, folded) so that when the animation finishes and the perspective layers are dismissed/removed from view, the actual model layers behind them are folded. The problem is that doing so also changes the presentation layers position (they are no longer like this: https://i.imgur.com/NPNZw1i.png, but stacked/overlapped like a sandwitch, thus breaking the animation) while it has no logic reason (at least, to me) to change them.

Comment: Transforms are cumulative -- so while it *seems* like that should work, I think the problem is that the combination is not really doing what seems logical. If your goal is to leave the transforms at the end of the animation, leave those commented lines commented, and try setting all of the animations to `animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards` and `animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false`

Comment: @DonMag  This was originally my solution, however by doing what you are suggesting more issues are introduced: firstly it feels like a bad practice since the presentation layers are never deallocated, second i need to keep model and presentation layers synced as i need to revert the animation at a later time. Thanks for pointing me out about transforms, tomorrow i'm doing some research about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - a bit of playing around...

Looks like you need to flip the animations, since they're effectively "going backward."

```
private func animate() {
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        if self == nil { return }
        //self?.perspectiveLayer.speed = 0
    }
    
    firstJointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-85*Double.pi/180), 0, 1, 0)
    secondJointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(170*Double.pi/180), 0, 1, 0)
    bottomSleeve.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-165*Double.pi/180), 0, 1, 0)
    perspectiveLayer.bounds.size.width = 0
    perspectiveLayer.position.x = 600
    firstJointLayer.position.x = 0
    topShadow.opacity = 0.5
    middleShadow.opacity = 0.5

    var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -85*Double.pi/180
    firstJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    // flip 180 degrees
    animation.fromValue = 180*Double.pi/180
    // to 180 - 170
    animation.toValue = 10*Double.pi/180
    secondJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    // flip -180 degrees
    animation.fromValue = -180*Double.pi/180
    // to 180 - 165
    animation.toValue = -15*Double.pi/180
    bottomSleeve.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = sizeWidth
    animation.toValue = 0
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = positionX
    animation.toValue = 600
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    // As said above, i added this animation which is not included in the original project, as the firstJointLayer was translating his position from left to right along with the perspectiveLayer position, so i make a reverse translation in its relative system so that it is stationary in the mainView system
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = firstJointLayerPositionX
    animation.toValue = 0
    firstJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    topShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    middleShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    CATransaction.commit()
    
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks so much dude, you've been so patient and very helpful! Really appreciated :) Not sure why i haven't tested this out before, i think i tweaked the toValue but never the fromValue, my bad